# Closing a channel after a timeout

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I have a small Go program that makes a number of requests every tick (1 second). I'm attempting to make these requests concurrently. I want to count and log the number of successful requests made in one tick, and then move on. If requests don't complete in time, I don't want to block the main ticker.

The code below achieves this, but I don't believe I'm closing the channel in concurrentReqs correctly. As any requests that miss the deadline still log with the previous tick. I also believe the ticker in the main function will block waiting for the concurrentReqs to finish. I tried moving the `close(ch)` inside of the timeout case in my select, but this results in a 'send on closed channel' error.

My understanding is that using contexts with a deadline (probably set in my main ticker) might be a solution for this, but I'm struggling to wrap my head around them, and I wonder if there's something else I can try.

Note: the timeout in concurrentReqs is deliberately low, since I'm testing locally.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "net/http"
)

type response struct {
    num int
    statusCode int
    requestDuration time.Duration
}

func singleRequest(url string, i int, tick int) response {
    start := time.Now()
    client := http.Client{ Timeout: 100 * time.Millisecond }

    resp, _ := client.Get(url)
    fmt.Printf("%d: %d\n", tick, i)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    return response{statusCode: int(resp.StatusCode), requestDuration: time.Since(start)}
}

func concurrentReqs(url string, reqsPerTick int, tick int) (results []response){
    ch := make(chan response, reqsPerTick)
    timeout := time.After(20 * time.Millisecond) // deliberately low
    results = make([]response, 0)

    for i := 0; i < reqsPerTick; i++ {
        go func(i int, t int) {
            ch <- singleRequest(url, i, tick)
        }(i, tick)
    }

    for i := 0; i < reqsPerTick; i++ {
        select {
        case response := <- ch:
            results = append(results, response)
        case <- timeout:
            return
        }
    }
    close(ch)

    return
}

func main() {
    var url string = "http://end-point.svc/req"

    c := time.Tick(1 * time.Second)
    for next := range c {
        things := concurrentReqs(url, 100, next.Second())
        fmt.Printf("%s: Successful Reqs - %d\n", int(next.Second()), len(things))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to close the channel?

Comment: In case of time out you don't close the channel. The `close` should be in a `defer`. Not sure if this is your issue, but it's *an* issue :-)

Comment: even if you close channel, gorotines will finish execution and log them self, channel closure has no effect on whether 'singleRequest' gets executed as only its result is being pushed into channel

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use context with timeout for cancellation and timing out. Also I think using wait group and mutex protected result writing helps simplicity here by eliminating second loop.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type response struct {
    num             int
    statusCode      int
    requestDuration time.Duration
}

func singleRequest(ctx context.Context, url string, i int, tick int) (response, error) {
    start := time.Now()

    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return response{requestDuration: time.Since(start)}, err
    }

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return response{requestDuration: time.Since(start)}, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("%d: %d\n", tick, i)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    return response{statusCode: int(resp.StatusCode), requestDuration: time.Since(start)}, nil
}

func concurrentReqs(url string, reqsPerTick int, tick int) (results []response) {
    mu := sync.Mutex{}
    results = make([]response, 0)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < reqsPerTick; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int, t int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            response, err := singleRequest(ctx, url, i, tick)
            if err != nil {
                log.Print(err)
                return
            }
            mu.Lock()
            results = append(results, response)
            mu.Unlock()
        }(i, tick)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    return results
}

func main() {
    var url string = "http://end-point.svc/req"

    c := time.Tick(1 * time.Second)
    for next := range c {
        // You may want to wrap this in a goroutine to make sure tick is not skipped.
        // Otherwise if concurrentReqs takes more than a tick time for whatever reason, a tick will be skipped.
        things := concurrentReqs(url, 100, next.Second())
        fmt.Printf("%s: Successful Reqs - %d\n", int(next.Second()), len(things))
    }
}
```